# What is this unknown app on Oppo running Android 11?

Tags: applications, malware, home-screen, android-11, oppo

This app just popped up on my Oppo A74 running Android version 11 and I can't open it, and it doesn't have a name.

[image]

I haven't downloaded anything today, and this app only came a few hours ago, so there's no chance of it being an app whose icon the developer forgot to put in. I am also not using an external SD card.

I can move it around while holding but I can't delete it nor remove it from the home screen. Clicking it gives the following prompt "Failed to read app data. Cannot run the app". When I long-press it, only app info comes up, clicking that does nothing, it doesn't show any info.

What is this app? Is it safe?

Comment: this app is not installed

Comment: But the thing is, I haven't installed any app recently, but this still popped up

Comment: Connect your phone to a PC with installed Android SDK, enable ADB on your device, execute `adb logcat` on the PC and then try to start the app. Logcat should then contain the app package name (besides many other log lines).

Comment: Possible dupe: [What is this weird app on the homescreen of ColorOS 11? Is this a malware?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245597/44325)

Comment: Woah, thanks a lot for sending that Question,I think this is the same issue with my phone. And also thanks for editing my question to make it better for people to read

Answer (score 0):

I hate to possibly be the bearer of bad news, but that is the exact same icon  that appeared after i accepted a "system update" which sadly was NOT what it claimed. It's odd that the icon remains on your homescreen though so it may be something harmless.
You can read about it here
https://blog.malwarebytes.com/cybercrime/mobile/2021/04/android-system-update-malware-steals-photos-videos-gps-location/

Comment: Was the system update something that  was in your settings, and you updated it,or did it come in some other form? And also, that app disappeared for me after I restarted my phone, is that similar to what app is mentioned in the article?

Comment: Wasn't in my settings.  It just popped up when i turned my phone on . Then it was listed in hidden system apps . I googled the version number it listed and it was the fake update. Never found a way to remove it . Just ended up getting a new phone.

Comment: Ok,thanks a lot.