# What is this weird app on the homescreen of ColorOS 11? Is this a malware?

Tags: applications, malware, home-screen, android-11, oppo-coloros

My device is an Oppo F11 Pro that I bought in 2019 and it has ColorOS 11.1 / Android 11.

Recently, this weird app popped out on my phone.

[image]

I tried to remove it, but when I tap on it, it says that it wasn't able to open the app, and when I hold the icon, I only get "see the details of this app" which leads to nothing. I found nothing on the app manager, so I thought that my phone was compromised and I reset it to factory settings and changed my passwords using my laptop (which I'm sure isn't compromised because I just got it and only has Firefox on it).

After the resetting, I installed some apps from the Play Store (as you see, Citymapper for example) and I noticed that for some apps (Messenger, Google Podcasts, Forest, and Reddit), this weird icon appears before the apps' icons; while for other icons (Citymapper, Instagram, McAfee Security), nothing happens. And since I got the McAfee 30 days trial, I decided to put it on the phone and it found nothing during its analysis.

I may have randomly found a hint about the app. I was checking the authorizations given to my apps and I noticed that an app called "DMApp" with the same weird Android icon had the authorization for making and managing phones calls. I removed it and there is no way to find that "DMApp" again, but the icons kept multiplicating.

**TL;DR:** A weird-looking icon keeps popping out in my phone with no way to find its origins (even after factory reset). Device: Oppo F11 Pro (bought in 2019). OS: ColorOS 11.1 | Android 11

I hope you can help me figure out what all this is about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Color OS bug with Android 11. Me too facing this since a few days so can confirm.

Comment: Oh ok thanks man that's really reassuring. So it's nothing dangerous ^^' Do you have any official source please? I can't seem to find it on their website.

Comment: actually that's happening because of partially downloaded apps.. and something is just wrong with play store and color os so those apps remain as that in home screen. You're seeing them only on the homescreen but not in the main apps drawer right?

Comment: Yeah only on the homescreen nothing in the main apps drawer. That's why I got suspicious haha.

Comment: @Daviiid i dont have any official backing but trust me there's nothing to worry unless you have installed some modded apps from external sources. If not, it's the play store bug as i said above.

Comment: thanks a lot! That's reassuring. Hope they fix the bug quickly before we have an army of these icons on our homescreens haha.

Comment: understandable.. For now, to avoid that, always make sure any application you're installing has been fully installed- in simple words, DON'T cancel any app that you've started to install from Google play. If you don't want those icons but still don't need an app, wait for it to fully install and then uninstall it.

Comment: Oh okay that totally makes sense, I'm having a really bad connection (no Wifi and at best I'm having H+, otherwise it's 3G) so it happens that I have to click on the install button in the app's page on the PlayStore many times. Thanks for everything!

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings - Homescreen and lockscreen, and turn off and on the icon autofill. It will clear off all those.